# The Post Method is not supported (Laravel)

Tags: laravel

Estoy haciendo  haciendo un formulario  y me sale un error al enviar el dato, he probado distintas soluciones  que he visto, pero no cambia nada. Estos son mis datos

```
**web.php**

Route::resource('producto','productosController');

**formulario**

<form method='post' action='/productos'>
   <input type='text' name='Nombre'>
     @crs
   <input type='submit value='enviar'>

</form>


**productosController**

public function store (Request $request){

   $producto = new Produucto;
   $producto->nombre = $request->nombre;
   $producto->save();
```

pd. new Produucto es correcto, me equivoque al hacer la migración

Comment: La uri de tu ruta es `producto`,  y en el action del form estás poniendo `productos`

Comment: Era eso debia poner /productos ..

Comment: También tienes un error de sintaxis en `@crs`

Comment: @csrf, también eso lo tienes mal escrito

Comment: Bueno, eso lo puse mal aquí, que lo escribí a mano, pero sí